# Ora2pg migrate from dmp file with blobs

Tags: postgresql, oracle19c, ora2pg

I have a large .dmp file exported from Oracle 19c (43GB) with several tables having files saved as blobs approx 1-10 MB in size.

I am trying to migrate this to a Postgres database. I tried using the following command:

```
C:\oracle-dumpfiles>ora2pg -t TABLE -c C:\ora2pg\ora2pg.conf -i C:\oracle-dumpfiles\export_2024-03-04.dmp -o output.sql -d mydatabase -u user -p password
```

and it starts the process with the following prompts but eventually runs out of memory:

```
C:\oracle-dumpfiles>ora2pg -t TABLE -c C:\ora2pg\ora2pg.conf -i C:\oracle-dumpfiles\export_2024-03-04.dmp -o output.sql -d mydatabase -u user -p password
[2024-03-19 11:32:43] Ora2Pg version: 24.1
[2024-03-19 11:32:43] Export type: TABLE
[2024-03-19 11:32:43] Geometry export type: INTERNAL
[2024-03-19 11:32:43] Exporting tables...
Out of memory!
```

My computer has 32GB ram and 150 GB of ssd storage.

I have tried reducing the `DATA_LIMIT` and `BLOB_LIMIT` to 200 and 1 respectively. But it still throws that error of Out of memory. Here are some of the settings in my .conf:

```
TYPE        TABLE
.
.
.
DATA_LIMIT  200
.
.
.
BLOB_LIMIT  1
.
.
.
LONGREADLEN 10475520
.
.
.
LOB_CHUNK_SIZE  5120000
```

Please help - any suggestions are appreciated, and happy to provide more settings if required to troubleshoot.